# How did I pass this "test" in the "First questions" review queue when there was no way I passed it?

Tags: support, review-audit

So I was on the Stack Exchange today when I looked at my review queues and saw that I had a notification for the "First questions" queue, and when I click on it, I get [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4684053/1160540) question to review. Now here's the thing: According to the queue, this question has no upvotes/downvotes.

As someone who doesn't do the queues often, I make the mistake of only *briefly* looking the question over, and decide that because of what I am seeing, the correct action would probably be to downvote the question (because the question seemed to be of poor quality).

Now here's the thing: When I clicked the button to downvote it, my screen then changes to show the question that I had just downvoted to have *19 votes* and  $2$ answers, one with $22$ votes, and the other having $7$, and I was told that it was a test, and that I passed.

---

#### My question

---

How come I passed this test review when clearly, the question that I had marked as not being clear/showing enough research had been very well received by the community?

---

##### To clarify

---

1. I am sorry if the [review](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/review) tag would be better suited to my question than the [review-audit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/review-audit) tag, however, I feel like the [review-audit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/review-audit) tag would be better suited for the question because this is more dealing with the review "tests" that help new users of the review queue hone their skills and try to get experienced users back on track when the system feels like they haven't been paying attention to what they have been reviewing.
2. If I'm interpreting what is being said here correctly, as [@Martin Sleziak](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users/8297/martin-sleziak) pointed out, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/first-questions/1961931) would be the link to the audit that I received, and while I admit I am sort of embarrassed that I received this, I feel like it would just be best to put the link in, because at least I passed it. :\

Comment: Just in case you want to link directly to the review audit, here is the link: https://math.stackexchange.com/review/first-questions/1961931

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks for the link to the review audit, I should probably edit my post to include that if that would be acceptable in terms of what M.SE Meta would want for links to clarify info. (if that makes sense at all)

Comment: It does seem strange at first glance, however the First Question review audit may not be concerned with your downvote.  The internal details are not known to me, but it might be that the action taken was "No further action needed" (after you downvoted), and this got interpreted as the correct course.

Comment: @hardmath I didn't press anything after downvoting, it seems to me that it was automatically interpreted as the correct course, but I am unsure why.

Comment: How did that question ever get 20 upvotes?

Comment: The question(not the meta) is rather borderline, and I am also genuinely confused about how it received so much attention and upvotes. It would've made more sense if this happened 10 years ago when our standards were lower.